# Can a page inside an iframe "see" cross domain if the iframe element itself is visible or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, iframe, cors

If I load a page in an iframe from a different domain, is there anyway for the contained page to see if the iframe element or it's parent element is visible (e.g. using jquery's `is(':hidden')`)?

I have control over both domains -- I can set CORS, attributes, whatever. Everything I try still gives me something like:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://s-college.mydomain.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://qaf.ng.mydomain.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

If it helps, the base domains are actually the same, just the sub-domains are different.

Comment: as far as I know, no.

Comment: can use postMessage API since you have control over both domains. Another way to use direct access is setting `document.domain` to match in both, then you can use same code as if it was iframe on same domain

Comment: Does CORS have nothing to do with this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are both on the same high level domain (e.g. `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`) you can set `document.domain` in JavaScript.

```
document.domain = 'example.com';
```

This will allow cross frame communication.

CORS only applies to (mostly AJAX) requests so it is not applicable here.

Just in case anyone else finds this question that doesn't have them on the same higher level domain: If they are on different domains you would need to use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) in order to communicate cross frame.